# Android Studio ¿Como logro que mi texto no traspase otras vistas por su largo?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Descripción de la imágen:**

Esta es una vista de un recycler view con la cual estoy teniendo un problema al intentar conectar el txt que es un mensaje con el txt que es un círculo azul.

**Descripción del problema:**

Quiero lograr el mismo efecto que en WhatsApp con los mensajes. Cuando están dentro de whatsapp y les llega un mensaje largo, este choca contra el círculo verde el cual indica mediante números la cantidad de mensajes nuevos sin leer. Cuando el texto del mensaje choca contra el círculo verde, este devuelve en su parte final tres puntos suspensivos "...". Esto es justo lo que quiero lograr pero como ven en mi imágen, no estoy pudiendo.

**Código XML de las vistas de mi Recycler View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraint_chat"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/seleccion_popup_chat"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_nombre_item_row_chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
    android:text="Cristian Domineck"
    android:textColor="#3C3A3A"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_mensaje_item_row_chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="228dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Si, podes."
    android:textColor="#7C7C7C"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_nuevo_mensaje"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_nombre_item_row_chat" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_mensaje_item_row_chat">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_estado_mensaje_item_row_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
        android:text="Recibido a las 20:28"
        android:textColor="#8F8E8E"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_visto"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circulo_nuevo_mensaje"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_estado_mensaje_item_row_chat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_barra"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_nuevo_mensaje"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_nombre_item_row_chat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_nuevo_mensaje"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circulo_nuevo_mensaje"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="12"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: Remueve el MarginEnd que tiene `txt_mensaje_item_row_chat`. De igual forma puedes asignarle `0dp` al `width` porque ya tiene restricciones de start y end, eso te asegura que el textView comprende esa área de la restricción. Debes tener cuidado cuando asignas márgenes con restricciones o asignar width específicos, ya que si la restricción cumple el ancho dinámico, se le asignará ese espacio extra, empujando tus vistas fuera de la restricción. Otra cosa, si no quieres multiline por si el mensaje es muy largo, te recomiendo acortarlo y agregar `...` (asignar una cantidad máxima de caracteres).

Comment: De nuevo gracias por responder Andres pero estos comentarios no me sirvieron. Solo me hiciste mención de algunas cosas pero sin explicarme como aplicarlo. Primero mencionas algo que si puedo hacer y es eliminar el margin end. Luego también me dices otra cosa que si puedo hacer que es asignarle 0dp al width porque mi texto tiene restricciones start y end pero justo antes de eso me dijiste que borre el end, por lo que ahora no se que hacer con el width. Por último, me recomiendas agregar los puntos suspensivos "..." los cuales no tengo idea de como agregar al chocar con el círculo azul.

Comment: Hola Andres. Sigo intentanto interpretar tus respuestas y buscando soluciones para este problema y la verdad es que no estoy logrando resolverlo. Me podrías facilitar otra ayuda?

Comment: Mmm, yo lo probé y me funciona, puse tu código en el Designer. Solo reduje el marginEnd a 15dp y el layout_width puse 0dp a `txt_mensaje_item_row_chat`. Dices que haciendo eso no te funciona?

Comment: Mil disculpas. No había comprendido bien y por ese motivo no lo intenté. No puedo creer que me funcionó. Estoy muy agradecido!

Comment: Perfecto, si puedes, borra las preguntas que no tengan respuestas para que no quede abierta. Saludos, cualquier duda estamos aquí.